# How to Execute Javascript on Selenium RC with PHP

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I need to execute javascript from selenium RC, anyone have any idea on how to do it?

I tried the following:

wrote the following custom function in user-extensions.js:

```
function sayhello() {
    document.write('hello');
}
```

and called it in WelcomeCept.php as follows:

```
<?php

$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wait(3000);
selenium.getEval('sayhello');
```

**Command:**

php codecept.phar run acceptance WelcomeCept.php

**Result:**

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.5.5 Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian
Bergmann.

Suite acceptance started PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
getEval() in
/home/user/Projects/selenium/tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php on line
103



FATAL ERROR OCCURRED. TESTS NOT FINISHED. Call to undefined function
getEval()  in
/home/user/Projects/selenium/tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php:103
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, including `sayhello` in double quotes `""` instead of single quotes `''` will serve your purpose.

**EDIT** single or double quotes is not the culprit. I'm trying to debug the issue.

Comment: It says : Call to undefined function
getEval()

Comment: check if you are getting the same error for selenium.runscript('sayhello()');

Comment: Check the below link in Stackoverflow. you may get some idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321255/how-do-i-inject-a-js-function-in-my-selenium-tests